# Why do God need relationship?

Tags: gods

I'm a hindu girl I used to visit temple daily and devotee of lord Vishnu. Once my friend (she belongs to other religion) asked me that why your hindu gods needs relationship such as wife, children etc. Please Anyone helps me to answer her..

Comment: Reason for this is past Karma and Vasanas but again everything is Maya of Lord.

Comment: Think like this, if you go to a first standard classroom, your goal is to explain 'what is a magnetic field'. How would you explain that? Would you say 'an electromagnetic field is a field of force that consists of both electric and magnetic components, resulting from the motion of an electric charge and containing a definite amount of electromagnetic energy.'? Who would understand? Probably you would say 'when you take a metal near the magnet, it gets attracted, that area around the magnet is called the magnetic field'. Even that might be too technical. You have to tell in a way they get that

Comment: Similarly, God is formless, attributeless and nameless (according to Advaita). How can we, whose minds have been conditioned by money, wealth, pride, anger, ego, jealousy, worldly life, attachments, family, etc. understand the abstract Brahman, who is Gunatita, Kalatita, Dehatita, Namatita, Avastatita, Bhavatita, etc. Therefore the Infinite Brahman, takes up a human-like form, with human-like attributes, and human-like family values, etc. in order that you may begin to take notice of the God and eventually by sacrificing the animalistic senses, you Will realize the Truth. :) All the best!!

Answer (score 10):

**God is not in the Relationship but Relationships themselves are due to God.** God himself creates this relationship by the power of his Maya.

For e.g. Adi Shankara in Dakshinmurty Stotram tells:

> विश्वं पश्यति कार्यकारणतया स्वस्वामिसम्बन्धतः
>   शिष्याचार्यतया तथैव पितृपुत्राद्यात्मना भेदतः ।
>   स्वप्ने जाग्रति वा य एष पुरुषो मायापरिभ्रामितः
>   तस्मै श्रीगुरुमूर्तये नम इदं श्रीदक्षिणामूर्तये ॥८॥ 
>  
>   **He whose power of Maya which enables one to See the World** as Cause and Effect, **as Possessor-Possession Relations,** as the Disciple-Teacher, and Also **as Father-Son Relations etc,** are all Differentiations within the One Atman, In Dream or Waking state, He, the One Purusha is always present, and (as if) Maya Wanders over Him and gives rise to all these Differentiations, Salutations to Him, the Personification of Our Inner Guru Who Awakens This Knowledge through His Profound Silence; Salutation to Sri Dakshinamurthy.

So, the Relationship of God and relationship of ourselves also which we perceive are simply due to potency of Lord. ie. **Relationship itself is perceived due to power of Lord.**

Answer (score 6):

Hindu gods do not need relationships. It is how ordinary humans whose minds are not capable of grasping the infinite in all its fullness view God.

> No one, except the perfected sage, can worship Him in His fullness,
>   since the human mind can grasp only limited aspects of Him. The more
>   an individual or a community is evolved, the more noble and
>   comprehensive will be their conception of the Deity. But the less
>   evolved man too is adoring the same Deity, grasping such aspects of
>   His as his undeveloped mind would allow. It is just like various forms
>   being chipped from a huge block of marble. The more skilled the
>   workman, the more artistic will be the forms chipped out of the block.
>   Even if it is crude, it is of the same block. Such are the various
>   conceptions of the Deity; **none can claim that his conception embraces
>   the whole of Him, because He cannot be contained within the limitation
>   of a mind, as a bottle cannot contain the whole of the sea.** He reveals
>   only what one is fit to receive. So according to the stages of human
>   evolution, there will be different conceptions of the Deity, and the
>   followers of one, even if they think theirs is more refined, need not
>   look down upon others as heathens or Kaffirs worshipping false
>   Deities, and consider themselves alone as the followers of the true
>   Deity.

Srimad Bhagavad Gita translated by Swami Tapasyananda